# find and replace one number with another

Tags: shell, sed

I have created a `0,1,2` genotype matrix and I want to replace all of the `-1` with `9`.

```
0   0   -1  0   0   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   -1
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   -1   1
0   0   2   0   0   -1  2   0   0   0   -1  0    0
```

I tried this:

```
sed -ie 's/^[-1] /9 /' file1 > file2
```

but it seems that it does not work.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: The `[]` enclose a collection of characters, so each occurrence of either `-` or `1` matches, but the `^` anchors the expression to the beginning of the line, so you don't get any match. You also miss the `g` flag to handle multiple occurences in a line.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/-1/9/g' file > file2
```

Comment: Place a space behind the `9` or you'll break the columns.

Comment: What about some number `-10`?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/-1/9 /g' file
sed 's/-1/9 /g' file1 > file2
```

Comment: This would affect any field that _starts_ with `-1`, e.g. `-11`.

Answer (score 0):

To do it in safe manner:

```
sed -e '
   s/$/ /
   :a;s/ -1 / 9 /;ta
   s/.$//
' file1
```

where

- `s/$/ /` insert a space at end of line
- `:a;s/ -1 / 9 /;ta` do substitution (space is needed if -1 at end of line)
- `s/.$//` remove space from end of line

Answer (score 0):

Your command,

```bsh
sed -ie 's/^[-1] /9 /' file1 > file2
```

does not work for two main reasons:

1. It changes the file in-place and backs the original up as `file1e`.  It does this because you instruct `sed` to use the letter `e` as the backup prefix when you use `-ie`. You `file2` file will be empty since the result is written back into `file1`.
2. Your regular expression, `^[-1]` , does not match anything.  The `^` will anchor the expression at the very start of the line, and in the example data that you have provided, the character at the start of each line is `0`.

   - Fixing this by removing `^` does not work, because `[-1]` only matches a *single* character, either a `-` or a `1`.  This means that the `sed` expression `s/[-1] /9 /` would replace the first `-` or `1` followed by a space on each line with `9` followed by a space.
   - Adding the `/g` flag at the end would not help as this would still erroneously  replace any `1` that is not `-1`, and it would additionally fail to replace an `-1` at the very end of the line where there is no trailing space.

Instead, substitute each `-1` with `9`, and also be careful with not replacing the `-1` substring of numbers such as `-10`:

```bsh
sed 's/-1\>/9/g' file1 >file2
```

The expression `-1\>` will match the string `-1` wherever it occurs with no trailing word characters (letters or digits).  It will therefore *not* match `-10` or `-11` etc.

Since you seem to want to write the result to `file2`, I don't use the `-i` option for in-place editing.  I also don't need to use an `-e` option to specify the `sed` expression, as there is only one expression.

---

To not have to bother about regular expressions, you laso have the option of using `awk` to replace the numbers:

```bsh
awk '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == -1) $i = 9 }; 1' file1 >file2
```

This iterates over each whitespace-delimited field on each line and replaces each that is numerically equal to -1 with 9.

This would replace the field delimiter on each modified line with a space.  If you want to use another delimiter than space, set tho `OFS` variable on the command line:

```bsh
awk -v OFS='\t' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) if ($i == -1) $i = 9 }; 1' file1 >file2
```

Answer (score -4):

I found the answer

```
sed -E 's/[-1] / 9/' file1 > file2
```

can do the job

Comment: No, sorry, it can't. `[-1]` matches a single character, a dash or a `1`.